# Как определить, нажата ли кнопка

Tags: java, android

На некоторых наушниках есть одна кнопка, обычно она принимает/завершает звонок и вызывает google поиск. Как можно программно определить, нажата ли кнопка?
P.S. Андроид разработка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не факт, что предложенный ниже способ сработает, но все же следует попробовать.

Дело в том, что при подобных событиях система Android не обделяет ни одно приложение от получения сведений об этом и шлет широковещательный интент всем, кто хочет его принять (и сопутствующую информацию).

Попробуйте отлавливать широковещательным приемником событие **[ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON)**, которое система посылает при нажатии на одну из медийных кнопок. В экстра-полях полученного интента (намерения) будет в таком случае содержаться код нажатой медиа кнопки. Выясните, какой номер имеет кнопка на наушниках и действуйте далее.

Подробнее почитайте в официальных руководствах, ссылка на которые выше.

Answer (score 0):

В manifest приложения можно указать приоритет. А вообще вот сюда загляните: [Controlling Your App’s Volume and Playback](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html).

> A good user experience is a predictable one. If your app plays media it’s important that your users can control the volume of your app using the hardware or software volume controls of their device, bluetooth headset, or headphones.